# VBScript Invalid Character Error 800A0408 on SQL Insert

Tags: sql, vbscript

I am trying to insert data into a SQL database using a VBScript, but the script will not compile due to an invalid character (the double quote before InitialCatalog).

I have checked the encoding (ANSI), I have tried deleting and retyping the quote to make sure it's not a "curly quote", I have added additional spaces to make sure that the error follows the quotation mark, I have tried replacing the quote with chr(34) and I have even created a new file and retyped the entire script to make sure there was no copy and paste related errors.  I am stumped.  Here is the entire script:

```
Const adOpenStatic = 3
Const adLockOptimistic = 3

Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

objConnection.Open _
"Provider=SQLOLEDB;" & _
"Data Source=******;" & _
"Trusted_Connection=Yes;" & _ "InitialCatalog=ERO;" & _
"User ID=*****;Password=*****;"

objRecordSet.Open "INSERT INTO Documents (RONumber, Description, FileName)" &  _
    "VALUES ('12345', 'RO', objArgs(0))", _
        objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Did you ever get this solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is the "_" before the double-quote, not the double-quote.  You need a `_` at the end of a line you intend to continue on the next line, but (unless I much mistake) anywhere else, it's a syntax error.

By the way, your SQL is probably going to fail because, rather than passing the value of `objArgs(0)`, you've baked the string literal "objArgs(0)" into the SQL.  SQL isn't going to know what that is.

Comment: Also, might need a space between `FileName)` and `VALUES`.

Comment: That makes sense - I must have taken out a line break without remving the underscore. There were a few other minor bugs that were easy enough to work through once the code would run. Thanks!